# Training and testing data in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, k-means

I want to train data using K-means algorithm and then test it over another similar kind of data removing only one column. I am new to machine learning, and so have taken the code from https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/k-means-clustering-python to apply on one of my datasets, but in this website where does the prediction part take place? We are just giving data and testing the accuracy. How can we apply the algorithm on test data (which obviously will be different) to predict the value of the missing attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion you have is very common when you are getting started with machine learning.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning):

> Supervised learning is the machine learning task of learning a
>   function that maps an input to an output based on example input-output
>   pairs. It infers a function from labeled training data consisting
>   of a set of training examples. In supervised learning, each example
>   is a pair consisting of an input object (typically a vector) and a
>   desired output value (also called the supervisory signal). A
>   supervised learning algorithm analyzes the training data and produces
>   an inferred function, which can be used for mapping new examples. An
>   optimal scenario will allow for the algorithm to correctly determine
>   the class labels for unseen instances. This requires the learning
>   algorithm to generalize from the training data to unseen situations in
>   a "reasonable" way (see inductive bias).

Also from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning):

> Unsupervised learning is a branch of machine learning that learns from
>   test data that has not been labeled, classified or categorized.
>   Instead of responding to feedback, unsupervised learning identifies
>   commonalities in the data and reacts based on the presence or absence
>   of such commonalities in each new piece of data.

The K-means clustering algorithm is an **Unsupervised** learning algorithm. 
In unsupervised learning you don't have labels because you are not trying to predict something. Instead you are trying to find a way to cluster your data in a way that data points with common characteristics are grouped together.

The reason why you use test (and often [validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_validation,_and_test_sets)) sets in Supervised learning in the first place, is to evaluate the generalization properties of your model in order to avoid [over-fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting#Machine_learning). In unsupervised learning however, you can't evaluate this since you don't know the actual clusters of the data. For this reason there is no point to use a test set.

Comment: OK so that is the reason why we need not train data in K-means clustering. You only need to provide a dataset and predict the value of output and just check the accuracy. Correct?

Comment: Correct, however usually you can't check accuracy for k-means since you don't know the actual outputs. Generally, it's almost always better to use a supervised algorithm(e.g SVM) when you know the actual answers. 'Hiding' the output labels and training an unsupervised algorithm is a very bad practice and will almost never give you good results (62% in your case). I highly suggest you to read [this](https://www.kaggle.com/nadintamer/titanic-survival-predictions-beginner) for a better way to approach this, and [this](https://mubaris.com/posts/kmeans-clustering/) for better use cases for k-means.

Comment: Does the same follow for Fuzzy C-means algorithm ?

Comment: It follows the same for any unsupervised or clustering algorithm.